# solrnet, solr grouping and ngroups parameter

Tags: solr, pagination, grouping, solrnet

I use grouping with solr 3.3 and solrnet.

I want to paginate results using the number of grouping result. Solr allows this with ngroups parameter.

is it possible to use this parameter with solrnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Solr grouping is available as of 0.4.0 alpha1, but the 'ngroups' parameter in particular is not implemented. Please file a [new issue](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/list), feel free to [fork the repository](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet) and implement it (it should be quite easy)

**EDIT**: OP sent a patch for this, it's now available in the master branch!

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/FieldCollapsing). Field collapsing seems to be broken, you have to fix it (link provided at bottom of the page)

Comment: I've seen this. But i use the version 4.0 alpha of solrnet with solr 3.3. You can see an example of grouping following this link : http://fleetstar.blogspot.com/2011/06/solrnet-grouping-example.html

Comment: ok, then queryOptions.Rows = 20; (in the example) means that you access row=1 for first group, row=2 second group and so on, so maybe you're looking to use this param instead of ngroups

Comment: I need to use "ngroups" with "row" and "start" to paginate. If I only use "row", I don't know how many results solr found and i can't paginate results. "Ngroups" give the number of group found.

Comment: @Samuele: please follow the links you posted. http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=127 is already implemented.